# Display cron job times in a human-friendly format

Tags: shell-script, cron, python

Is there a way to display or is there a tool that can parse a crontab expression and display it in a human-friendly way?

`10 6 * * * sh /usr/local/crons/file_check.sh`

For example, for the above cron I want the time on the above cronjob to be displayed as

`06:10 hrs`

or in any other human-friendly way.

Currently, I have decided to go with writing a shell script or python to manipulate the output of `crontab -l` to display it in a way a non-technical person can understand when the job will be run next, but if there is a direct method, it would be great.

P.S:- A bash or python solution is preferred.

Comment: found this after googling: https://github.com/RedHogs/cron-parser

Comment: Thanks @Dārayavahuštdi . Yes, but I am more inclined towards a shell or python solution.

Comment: If you're open to Perl, you can use the script linked from here: http://interglacial.com/~sburke/pub/crontab2english.html

Comment: This may be more complicated than you think, given ranges and whatnot; you really want something already written and fleshed out.  See the docs for @zackse's link to crontab2english.

Comment: [CronChecker](http://www.cronchecker.net/) is a web service, however the source code is on GitHub. It´s basically a Ruby on Rails app, but I´m sure somebody can extract the parsing functionality to use it as a independent library. https://github.com/pbyrne/cron-checker/blob/master/app/models/cron_parser.rb

Comment: The thing is, it's already human readable. `10 6 * * *` -> tenth minute of the sixth hour of every day of every month, on any day of the week.  `*/6 4 */2 * *` -> every sixth minute of the fourth hour of every second day of every month, on any day of the week.

Comment: An answer on [a newer question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/685362/print-the-cron-time-in-human-readable-format?rq=1) suggests a package [hcron](https://github.com/lnquy/cron).
(It's not yet in repos, though, it seems.)

Answer (score 1):

As you want a Python solution:

https://pypi.org/project/cron-descriptor/

I have not tried it. It's just one of the first things that pop up when you search for `cron` in pypi.

Answer (score 1):

check this github solution. its bash script. i didn't try/test this solution.

https://github.com/inthuriel/human-cron/blob/master/human-cron.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash
################################################
# bash script                                  #
# author Mikolaj 'Metatron' Niedbala           #
# displays user crontab in human readable form #
# based on `crontab` command                   #
# need to specify user                         #
# licenced GNU/ GPL                            #
################################################

if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
    echo "Podaj uzytkownika CRON, dla ktorego wyswietlic tabele"
    exit 1;
fi;

echo -e "Lista komend do wykonania dla uzytkownika $1\n"    
crontab -l -u $1 | while read line
    do 
        if [[ ! $line =~ ^\# && ! -z $line ]]; then
            COMBINED_DATE=0
            TIME_str=""
            DATE_str=""

            #explode to values
            COMMAND=`echo "$line" | sed 's/^\(.\{1,8\} \)\{5\}//'`
            MINUTES=`echo "$line" |cut -d" " -f1`
            HOUR=`echo "$line" |cut -d" " -f2`
            MONTH_DAY=`echo "$line" |cut -d" " -f3`
            MONTH=`echo "$line" |cut -d" " -f4`
            WEEK_DAY=`echo "$line" |cut -d" " -f5`

            #command string
            ECHO_str="komenda $COMMAND zostanie wykonana"

            #process values
                #hours
                if [[ ! $HOUR =~ ^\*$ && ! -z $HOUR ]]; then
                    if [[ $HOUR =~ ^\*\/[0-9]{1,2}$ && ! -z $HOUR ]]; then
                        NUM_HOUR=`echo "$HOUR" |cut -d"/" -f2`;
                        HR_str="co $NUM_HOUR godzin";
                    elif [[ $HOUR =~ ^[0-9]{1,2}$ && ! -z $HOUR ]]; then
                        HR_str="o godzinie $HOUR"
                        COMBINED_DATE=1
                    elif [[ $HOUR =~ ^[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}$ && ! -z $HOUR ]]; then
                        FR_NUM_HOUR=`echo "$HOUR" |cut -d"-" -f1`;
                        TO_NUM_HOUR=`echo "$HOUR" |cut -d"-" -f2`;
                        HR_str="pomiedzy godzina $FR_NUM_HOUR a $TO_NUM_HOUR"               
                    elif [[ $HOUR =~ ^[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}$ && ! -z $HOUR ]]; then
                        NUM_HOUR=`echo "$HOUR" |cut -d"/" -f2`;
                        HOUR_RANGE=`echo "$HOUR" |cut -d"/" -f1`;
                        FR_NUM_HOUR=`echo "$HOUR_RANGE" |cut -d"-" -f1`;
                        TO_NUM_HOUR=`echo "$HOUR_RANGE" |cut -d"-" -f2`;
                        HR_str="pomiedzy godzina $FR_NUM_HOUR a $TO_NUM_HOUR, co $NUM_HOUR godziny"
                    fi;
                else
                    HR_str=""
                fi;

                #minutes
                if [[ ! $MINUTES =~ ^\*$ && ! -z $MINUTES ]]; then
                    if [[ $MINUTES =~ ^\*\/[0-9]{1,2}$ && ! -z $MINUTES ]]; then
                        NUM_MINUTES=`echo "$MINUTES" |cut -d"/" -f2`
                        MIN_str="co $NUM_MINUTES minut"
                    elif [[ $COMBINED_DATE == 1 ]]; then
                        if [[ ! $MINUTES =~ ^\*$ && ! -z $MINUTES ]]; then
                            MIN_str="$MINUTES"
                        else
                            MIN_str="w $MINUTES minucie"
                        fi;
                    elif [[ $MINUTES =~ ^[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}$ && ! -z $MINUTES ]]; then
                        FR_NUM_MINUTES=`echo "$MINUTES" |cut -d"-" -f1`;
                        TO_NUM_MINUTES=`echo "$MINUTES" |cut -d"-" -f2`;
                        MIN_str="pomiedzy $FR_NUM_MINUTES a $TO_NUM_MINUTES minuta"                     
                    elif [[ $MINUTES =~ ^[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}$ && ! -z $MINUTES ]]; then
                        NUM_MINUTES=`echo "$MINUTES" |cut -d"/" -f2`;
                        MINUTES_RANGE=`echo "$MINUTES" |cut -d"/" -f1`;
                        FR_NUM_MINUTES=`echo "$MINUTES_RANGE" |cut -d"-" -f1`;
                        TO_NUM_MINUTES=`echo "$MINUTES_RANGE" |cut -d"-" -f2`;
                        MIN_str="pomiedzy $FR_NUM_MINUTES a $TO_NUM_MINUTES minuta, co $NUM_MINUTES minuty"
                    fi;                 
                else
                    MIN_str=""
                fi;     

                #day of month
                if [[ ! $MONTH_DAY =~ ^\*$ && ! -z $MONTH_DAY ]]; then
                    if [[ $MONTH_DAY =~ ^\*\/[0-9]{1,2}$ && ! -z $MONTH_DAY ]]; then
                        NUM_MONTH_DAY=`echo "$MONTH_DAY" |cut -d"/" -f2`
                        MON_D_str="co $NUM_MONTH_DAY dni"
                    elif [[ $MONTH_DAY =~ ^[0-9]{1,2}$ && ! -z $MONTH_DAY ]]; then
                        MON_D_str="$MONTH_DAY dnia miesiaca"
                    elif [[ $MONTH_DAY =~ ^[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}$ && ! -z $MONTH_DAY ]]; then
                        FR_NUM_MONTH_DAY=`echo "$MONTH_DAY" |cut -d"-" -f1`;
                        TO_NUM_MONTH_DAY=`echo "$MONTH_DAY" |cut -d"-" -f2`;
                        MON_D_str="pomiedzy $FR_NUM_MONTH_DAY a $TO_NUM_MONTH_DAY dniem miesiaca"                       
                    elif [[ $MONTH_DAY =~ ^[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}$ && ! -z $MONTH_DAY ]]; then
                        NUM_MONTH_DAY=`echo "$MONTH_DAY" |cut -d"/" -f2`;
                        MONTH_DAY_RANGE=`echo "$MONTH_DAY" |cut -d"/" -f1`;
                        FR_NUM_MONTH_DAY=`echo "$MONTH_DAY_RANGE" |cut -d"-" -f1`;
                        TO_NUM_MONTH_DAY=`echo "$MONTH_DAY_RANGE" |cut -d"-" -f2`;
                        MON_D_str="pomiedzy $FR_NUM_MONTH_DAY a $TO_NUM_MONTH_DAY dniem miesiaca, co $NUM_MONTH_DAY dni"
                    fi;                     
                else
                    MON_D_str=""
                fi;             

                #month
                if [[ ! $MONTH =~ ^\*$ && ! -z $MONTH ]]; then
                    if [[ $MONTH =~ ^\*\/[0-9]{1,2}$ && ! -z $MONTH ]]; then
                        NUM_MONTH=`echo "$MONTH" |cut -d"/" -f2`
                        MON_str="co $NUM_MONTH miesiecy"
                    elif [[ $MONTH =~ ^[0-9]{1,2}$ && ! -z $MONTH ]]; then
                        MON_str="w $MONTH miesiacu"
                    elif [[ $MONTH =~ ^[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}$ && ! -z $MONTH ]]; then
                        FR_NUM_MONTH=`echo "$MONTH" |cut -d"-" -f1`;
                        TO_NUM_MONTH=`echo "$MONTH" |cut -d"-" -f2`;
                        MON_str="pomiedzy $FR_NUM_MONTH a $TO_NUM_MONTH miesiacem"                      
                    elif [[ $MONTH =~ ^[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}$ && ! -z $MONTH ]]; then
                        NUM_MONTH=`echo "$MONTH" |cut -d"/" -f2`;
                        MONTH_RANGE=`echo "$MONTH" |cut -d"/" -f1`;
                        FR_NUM_MONTH=`echo "$MONTH_RANGE" |cut -d"-" -f1`;
                        TO_NUM_MONTH=`echo "$MONTH_RANGE" |cut -d"-" -f2`;
                        MON_str="pomiedzy $FR_NUM_MONTH a $TO_NUM_MONTH miesiacem, co $NUM_MONTH miesiecy"
                    fi;                     
                else
                    MON_str=""
                fi;             

                #week day
                if [[ ! $WEEK_DAY =~ ^\*$ && ! -z $WEEK_DAY ]]; then
                    if [[ $WEEK_DAY =~ ^\*\/[0-9]{1,2}$ && ! -z $WEEK_DAY ]]; then
                        NUM_WEEK=`echo "$WEEK_DAY" |cut -d"/" -f2`
                        WEK_str="co $NUM_WEEK dni tygodnia"
                    elif [[ $WEEK_DAY =~ ^[0-9]{1,2}$ && ! -z $WEEK_DAY ]]; then
                        WEK_str="$WEEK_DAY dnia tygodnia"
                    elif [[ $WEEK_DAY =~ ^[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}$ && ! -z $WEEK_DAY ]]; then
                        FR_NUM_WEEK_DAY=`echo "$WEEK_DAY" |cut -d"-" -f1`;
                        TO_NUM_WEEK_DAY=`echo "$WEEK_DAY" |cut -d"-" -f2`;
                        WEK_str="pomiedzy $FR_NUM_WEEK_DAY a $TO_NUM_WEEK_DAY dniem tygodnia"                       
                    elif [[ $WEEK_DAY =~ ^[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}$ && ! -z $WEEK_DAY ]]; then
                        NUM_WEEK_DAY=`echo "$WEEK_DAY" |cut -d"/" -f2`;
                        WEEK_DAY_RANGE=`echo "$WEEK_DAY" |cut -d"/" -f1`;
                        FR_NUM_WEEK_DAY=`echo "$WEEK_DAY_RANGE" |cut -d"-" -f1`;
                        TO_NUM_WEEK_DAY=`echo "$WEEK_DAY_RANGE" |cut -d"-" -f2`;
                        MON_str="pomiedzy $FR_NUM_WEEK_DAY a $TO_NUM_WEEK_DAY dniem tygodnia, co $NUM_WEEK_DAY dni"
                    fi;                     
                else
                    WEK_str=""
                fi;

            #generate string for end user
            if [[ $COMBINED_DATE == 1 ]]; then
                if [[ $MIN_str =~ ^[0-9]{1}$ ]]; then
                    MIN_str="0$MIN_str"
                fi;                 
                TIME_str="$HR_str:$MIN_str, "
            else
                if [[ ! -z $HR_str ]]; then
                    TIME_str="$HR_str, "
                else
                    TIME_str="$TIME_str$MIN_str, "
                fi; 
            fi;

            if [[ ! -z $WEK_str || ! -z $MON_str || ! -z $MON_D_str ]]; then
                if [[ ! -z $WEK_str ]]; then
                    DATE_str="$WEK_str, "
                fi; 
                if [[ ! -z $MON_str ]]; then
                    DATE_str="$DATE_str$MON_str, "
                fi; 
                if [[ ! -z $MON_D_str ]]; then
                    DATE_str="$DATE_str$MON_D_str, "
                fi;                 
            else
                DATE_str="codziennie"
            fi; 

            if [[ $DATE_str =~ ^codziennie$ ]]; then
                echo "-+ $ECHO_str $DATE_str $TIME_str" | sed 's/.\{2\}$//'
            else                
                echo "-+ $ECHO_str $TIME_str $DATE_str" | sed 's/.\{2\}$//'
            fi; 

            echo "--"   
        fi;
done;
exit 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

For those searching for a quick and easy tool, try [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru).

So for example, the requested cron text:

```
10 6 * * *
```

[resolves to](https://crontab.guru/#10_6_*_*_*) *“At 06:10.”*