# cron - finding out when something will run

Tags: cron

I know there are sites out there that can tell you, from a cronjob time setup, when are the next times something will fire up.

Is there a command on GNU/Linux that could be used to know when will be the next times the cronjob setup will run? Like, `list me the next 5 times each one of the lines setup in my crontab will run`? Preferably CLI-based.

Comment: Related to: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/185642/display-cron-job-times-in-a-human-friendly-format/521716

Comment: Interesting. Nothing standard? Even better if it were part of the cron (anacron?) tools themselves.

Comment: `systemd-analyze calendar` works really well for this for systemd timers giving the next time the timer will elapse in UTC, local, and relative time from now.   Not sure about cron though.