# Print the cron time in human readable format

Tags: cron

After researching enough on the times when `cron.daily` (and `weekly` and 'hourly') run, I found the following command -

```
grep run-parts /etc/crontab
```

But the output of this command isn't very intuitive. If I want to see the corn running times in a human readable format, like the one given by the `date` command, what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `hcron` - [hcron](https://github.com/lnquy/cron) . You can specify a crontab file and it will parse it the way you would expect. My tip would be to rename the binary after extracting the package, because the binary defaults to the name `cron`.

Example output:

```
./hcron --file /var/spool/cron/root 
00 15 * * *: At 03:00 PM | command-foo
0 23 * * 5: At 11:00 PM, only on Friday | my-other-command-foo
```